# Stripe CLI `listen` not quitting after exit

Tags: shell, stripe-payments, command-line-interface

I've created a shell script to run my dev server, listen to stripe test hooks, and then exec my test scripts in firebase emulators.

```bash
npm run dev &
stripe listen -f http://0.0.0.0:5001/.../stripeWebhook &
firebase emulators:exec "npm run test" --import ./cypress/cypress/fixtures/firebase
```

This seems to work, but after it finishes the stripe process doesn't seem to exit and subsequent runs look like they're trying to process each stripe hook multiple times. How do I force the stripe CLI to stop listening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`stripe listen` command](https://stripe.com/docs/cli/listen) does not run in the background but rather streams the output to `stdout`.  Therefore I think it will not behave properly running in a shell script, especially when combined with other commands.  It is possible that your script is generating a listening process with each run and the event is being forwarded for each process.

I would stick to running `stripe listen` in a dedicated terminal session to ensure you get the expected behavior.

Comment: I think that's exactly what's happening. What I'm trying to avoid is having to run multiple terminals (for ease of development and so it can be integrated into some kind of deploy/ci process). If I spawn a `child_process` in a node script, would that have the same problem? Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: The CLI isn't intended to be a tool that serves this kind of purpose (ci/cd).  Stripe APIs are not really suited for automated testing either.  If the purpose of this is to test out how your code handles various webhook events I would create mock responses in JSON to match all the conditions you want to validate against. Use `stripe trigger` to generate example events you can copy and paste into a static file you could read from.  Not the most simple but it's the approach that will scale as your tests get more numerous and more complex.